# Hide flagged (inappropriate) comments from comment list

Tags: craft2, comments

Craft CMS V2.
Comment Plugin: [verbb comment](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments)

```
{% set comments = craft.comments.all({
    limit: 10,
    status: 'approved'
}) %}

{% for comment in comments %}
    {{ comment.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```

This query fetches all approved comments including flagged (Comment marked as inappropriate) comments because flagged comment status is 'approved'.

But I want to hide flagged comments from approved comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`isFlagged()` method](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/comments/v0/docs/developers/comment-model#methods) to only display non-flagged comments:

```
{% set comments = craft.comments.all({
    limit: 10,
    status: 'approved'
}) %}

{% for comment in comments if comment.isFlagged() == false %}
    {{ comment.comment }}
{% endfor %}
```